# Some games keeps crashing on LG Rebel 2

Tags: applications, crashes

I have LG Rebel 2. It has started to crash and go right back to my home screen when I play 1 or 2 of my games, like SimCity BuildIt crashes on loading screens even though I'll only have one app running at a time.

What is causing this?

Comment: how much ram do you have?

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow I looked it up, it is 1GB RAM.

Comment: This device only has 1GB of RAM, it is barely enough to function for basic phone use, much less game... You might want to consider that you just didn't purchase the right phone for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Base off of your description, it appears to be a RAM issue.

While 1GB RAM is usable for some games (from personal experience), some games will crash on the loading screen due to too little memory (I've experienced it with other games as well).

The best way to stop this is to lower the quality settings, if possible. Try Low or Very Low to use less RAM.

If that fails, try an app hibernating app like [Greenify.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) (This app works on non-rooted phones, but needs root in order to be more efficent). This will reduce the amount of background apps, freeing up more RAM.

If the above fails, try getting a better phone. There are a lot of phones on the market with 2GB RAM or more at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question, an application in an android phone crashes due to *low RAM* (random-access memory) which holds the processes of the certain app. If it runs low, then it forces the app/game to close to preserve other processes (the important ones especially the system processes).

Comment: So basicly, if I uninstall other apps it would free up more ram and in theory run smooth

Comment: Yes. Certainly, it would

Comment: @BrianHathaway Uninstalling apps will not increase your available RAM, well not significantly, it would increase your storage space available through just like deleting a file from the hard drive of your computer. You cannot really increase your RAM, that is based on the hardware inside the device and it is not upgradable. The reality is you have a device that has a very limited scope of abilities due to it's hardware, and it seems to be insufficient for your needs.

Answer (score -2):

according to your description, there may be several reasons:

1. Your Android phone has **too much cache**, and when the phone is too cached, the app will run slower and crash.
2. There are **too many running programs in the background** of your Android phone. The closed app just exits the desktop and is still running in the background.
3. The application is **not compatible with the system**. A low version of the app is not compatible with the phone's system, or the phone system version is too low that cannot play the game, which will cause a crash.
4. **Missing data package**. Crash is also caused by the lack of data packets when running the game. This can happen if the packet .obb file is deleted by mistake. Like most game of Gamaloft, if you lost .obb file, it will crash.

If you don't plan to change a mobile phone, you need to **clean your phone often**:

1. Navigate to Settings on your phone. Setting>>Apps>>Choose the app you don’t like>> uninstall or force stop.
2. Navigate to Settings on your phone. Setting>>Storage>>Cached Data.
3. Use **Agile File Manager** to free up your storage. It can simply delete cached files, along with miscellaneous files that are larger than 10 MB. The Boost option can closes apps you’re not using that are still running in the background.
4. The last thing to say is that for Android phones, restarting the phone can solve more than half of the problems. When your device has been running for a long time, and if it is a low-end phone. Rebooting the phone will erase all blocked apps and fix freezes and crashes on apps on Android devices.

Comment: I have deleted and fully uninstalled a few apps I don't really use. I clear all my cache data every night and any app I'm not using I have forced stopped them. Since deleting the apps it s÷ma to be running a lot better. Thanks all for tour advice.